# Выравнять текст по одной линии

Tags: html, css

Доброе утро, как выравнять этот текст (граммовки и цена) по одной линии как на картинке?

Заранее благодарен

Необходимый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что имеем на данный момент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
div.menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
  p {
    color: #838383;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
    span.title {
      font-family: Rodeoc;
      color: #c42213;
    }
    span.gramm {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
      color: #000;
      margin-left: 55px;
    }
    span.boldertext {
      font-size: 17px;
      font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
  }
  p.text {
    color: #000;
  }
  p.subtext {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #838383;
  }
}

p.subtext {
  font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #838383;
}

div.footermenu {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("../img/footermenu.png");
  width: 120%;
  height: 78px;
  right: -50px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
div.footermenu2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("../img/footermenu.png");
  width: 120%;
  height: 60px;
  right: -50px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

div.submenu {
  margin-top: 10px;
  p {
    font-family: Rodeoc;
    font-size: 18px;
    span.ml {
      font-family: Partner;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    span.price {
      font-size: 17px;
      font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <h4 class="text-center">КАМЧАТКА</h4>
    <h1 class="text-center">Рамен</h1>

    <div class="menu">
        <p>#7 <span class="title">Торидон</span> <span class="gramm">350г</span>
            <span class="boldertext">270 р.</span>
        </p>
        <p class="text">Рис, филе куриного бедра, соус</p>
        <p class="subtext">Белки: 9,5г; жиры: 6,2г; углеводы: 25,9г. Калорийность: 195 ккал*</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <p>#8 <span class="title">Кацудон</span> <span class="gramm">350г</span>
            <span class="boldertext">270 р.</span>
        </p>
        <p class="text">Рис, свиная отбивная в панировке, капуста</p>
        <p class="subtext">Белки: 9,5г; жиры: 5,5г; углеводы: 32,1г. Калорийность: 235 ккал</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <p>#9 <span class="title">Суп Мисо</span> <span class="gramm">170г</span>
            <span class="boldertext">60 р.</span>
        </p>
        <p class="text">Традиционный японский суп на основе рыбного бульона Хондаши, морских водорослей
        и соевого сыра Тофу</p>
        <p class="subtext">Белки: 2,1г; жиры: 1,2г; углеводы: 11,7г. Калорийность: 66 ккал</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <p>#10 <span class="title">Салат</span> <span class="gramm">170г</span>
            <span class="boldertext">55 р.</span>
        </p>
        <p class="text">Капуста, морковь, кукуруза, заправка</p>
        <p class="subtext">Белки: 1,5г; жиры: 1,1г; углеводы: 5,6г. Калорийность: 37,6 ккал</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <p>#11 <span class="title">Сет с Гедза</span> <span class="gramm"></span>
            <span class="boldertext">315 р.</span>
        </p>
        <p class="text">Гедза, суп Мисо, салат</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <p>#12 <span class="title">Сет с Торидоном</span> <span class="gramm"></span>
            <span class="boldertext">330 р.</span>
        </p>
        <p class="text">Торидон, суп Мисо</p>
    </div>

    <div class="submenu">
        <p>Чай в ассортименте <span class="ml">200 мл</span> <span class="price">60 p.</span></p>
        <p>Американо <span class="ml">200 мл</span> <span class="price">125 p.</span></p>
        <p>Капучино <span class="ml">200 мл</span> <span class="price">150 p.</span></p>
        <p>Латте <span class="ml">200 мл</span> <span class="price">160 p.</span></p>
        <p>Кока-кола / Фанта / Спрайт <span class="ml">200 мл</span> <span class="price">90 p.</span></p>
        <p>Вода << БонАква >> <span class="ml">200 мл</span> <span class="price">75 p.</span></p>
        <p>Чай << Нести >> <span class="ml">200 мл</span> <span class="price">75 p.</span></p>
        <p>Сок в ассортименте <span class="ml">200 мл</span> <span class="price">75 p.</span></p>
    </div>

    <p class="subtext">* Здесь и далее пищевая и энергетическая ценность указаны на 100 г продукта</p>

    <div class="footermenu2"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например:

```css
div.menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
div.menu p {
  color: #838383;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
}
div.menu p span.title {
  font-family: Rodeoc;
  color: #c42213;
}
div.menu p span.gramm {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 55px;
}
div.menu p span.boldertext {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
div.menu p.text {
  color: #000;
}
div.menu p.subtext {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #838383;
}

p.subtext {
  font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #838383;
}

div.footermenu {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("../img/footermenu.png");
  width: 120%;
  height: 78px;
  right: -50px;
  background-size: cover;
}

div.footermenu2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("../img/footermenu.png");
  width: 120%;
  height: 60px;
  right: -50px;
  background-size: cover;
}

div.submenu {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div.submenu p {
  font-family: Rodeoc;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div.submenu span.ml {
  font-family: Partner;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div.submenu span.price {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Partner, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 15px;
}


.menu {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <h4 class="text-center">КАМЧАТКА</h4>
      <h1 class="text-center">Рамен</h1>

      <div class="menu">
          <p>#7 <span class="title">Торидон</span> 
              <span class="right">
                <span class="gramm">350г</span>
                <span class="boldertext">270 р.</span>
              </span>
          </p>
          <p class="text">Рис, филе куриного бедра, соус</p>
          <p class="subtext">Белки: 9,5г; жиры: 6,2г; углеводы: 25,9г. Калорийность: 195 ккал*</p>
      </div>

      <div class="menu">
          <p>#8 <span class="title">Кацудон</span> 
            <span class="right">
              <span class="gramm">350г</span>
              <span class="boldertext">270 р.</span>
            </span>
          </p>
          <p class="text">Рис, свиная отбивная в панировке, капуста</p>
          <p class="subtext">Белки: 9,5г; жиры: 5,5г; углеводы: 32,1г. Калорийность: 235 ккал</p>
      </div>

      <div class="menu">
          <p>#9 <span class="title">Суп Мисо</span> 
            <span class="right">
              <span class="gramm">170г</span>
              <span class="boldertext">60 р.</span>
            </span>
          </p>
          <p class="text">Традиционный японский суп на основе рыбного бульона Хондаши, морских водорослей
          и соевого сыра Тофу</p>
          <p class="subtext">Белки: 2,1г; жиры: 1,2г; углеводы: 11,7г. Калорийность: 66 ккал</p>
      </div>

      <div class="submenu">
          <p>Чай в ассортименте 
            <span class="right">
              <span class="ml">200 мл</span> 
              <span class="price">60 p.</span>
            </span>
          </p>
          <p>Американо 
            <span class="right">
              <span class="ml">200 мл</span> 
              <span class="price">125 p.</span>
            </span>
          </p>
          <p>Капучино 
            <span class="right">
              <span class="ml">200 мл</span> 
              <span class="price">150 p.</span>
            </span>
          </p>
         
      </div>

      <p class="subtext">* Здесь и далее пищевая и энергетическая ценность указаны на 100 г продукта</p>

      <div class="footermenu2"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Граммы и цену объединить в общую обертку и выровнять по правой стороне.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - использовать flex:

```css
.name-item {
  display:flex;
}
.name-item  .title {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
   <div class="menu">
        <p class="name-item">#7 <span class="title">Торидон</span> <span class="gramm">350г</span>
            <span class="boldertext">270 р.</span>
        </p>
        <p class="text">Рис, филе куриного бедра, соус</p>
        <p class="subtext">Белки: 9,5г; жиры: 6,2г; углеводы: 25,9г. Калорийность: 195 ккал*</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <p class="name-item">#8 <span class="title">Кацудон</span> <span class="gramm">350г</span>
            <span class="boldertext">270 р.</span>
        </p>
        <p class="text">Рис, свиная отбивная в панировке, капуста</p>
        <p class="subtext">Белки: 9,5г; жиры: 5,5г; углеводы: 32,1г. Калорийность: 235 ккал</p>
    </div>
```